# cakephp, how to upload images

Tags: php, image, cakephp, upload

In my cake view, I have the following form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $this->base; ?>/reviews/upload/" method="post" target="_blank">
 <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In the ReviewsController, in the upload() method there is:

```
public function upload() {
    var_dump($this->request->data);        
}
```

but it's always empty! I already tried "this->request", "this->data" but it's always empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing it cake way,

```
echo $this->Form->create("Review", array("action" => "upload", "type" => "file"));
    echo $this->Form->input("my-file", array("type" => "file"));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

In your reviews controller

```
 public function upload() {
     debug($this->request->data);       
 }
```

Using debug over var_dump and print_r as advantage that debug can be turned off in production mode application wide by setting lowering the debug level to 0 in core.php

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the input to somethinge else then file. Had problems with that before!

Comment: Still, nothing there. Does anybody know how do I read my POST data in the controller?